# Is there a widget to query an ID an output different fields tied to that ID (from a dataframe or connected SQL table)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to include a widget in my Shiny dashboard that performs a query over my dataframe / connected SQL tables that output different fields from those datasets. I do not want the output to be displayed in a table, however.

Comment: And then what do you want to achieve with that table?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).